# Add a JSON Array to the return of a Server Side Event

Tags: javascript, json, server-sent-events

Currently I am writing data in JSON format, one message at a time like this:

```
String[] arr = strLine.split(",");

   out.append("data: {\n");
   out.append("data: \"c1\": " + arr[0].toString()+ ",\n");
   out.append("data: \"c2\": " + arr[1].toString()+ ",\n" );
   out.append("data: }\n\n");
   out.flush();
```

But, now I want to out.flush only when 5 such messages are there. So, how do I do this? create Json messages? with separate data:{ } body. And if I do so how do I access pairs of c1, c2 at client side with javascript? And what are the alternatives.

PS: When I say 5 values, I mean 5 pair of values of c1 and c2.

And how do I access values using javascript at client side, if I do something like this

```
out.append("data: [\n");
for(int j=0; j<5; j++) {
     String[] arr = strLine.split(",");
     if (j!=0) out.append(",\n");
     out.append("\{"c1\": " + arr[0].toString()+ ",\n");
     out.append(\"c2\": " + arr[1].toString()+"}" );
     out.flush();
  }
//HEY MR, LOOK BELOW ME
//HEY MR, LOOK BELOW ME
//HEY MR, LOOK BELOW ME
//HEY MR, LOOK BELOW ME
out.append("]\n"); <---- HEY RIGHT HERE 
//HEY MR, LOOK ABOVE ME
//HEY MR, LOOK ABOVE ME
//HEY MR, LOOK ABOVE ME
//HEY MR, LOOK ABOVE ME
out.flush();
```

Working JS code as requested ( calling registerSSE() on body load):

```
function registerSSE(){
  var source = new EventSource ('http://localhost:8080/SSE_Test1/ReadCsv');
  source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
  console.log(data.timestamp, data.c1, data.c2, data.c3, data.c4);
}
```

And in servlet you just need to append this line:

```
response.setContentType("text/event-stream");
```

Comment: Hi Shusl, No this is java code in my servlet. I writing data in json format in servlet and trying to read it at client side using javascript. Hope I answered what you are asking :)

Comment: I should have at first place, thank You !

Comment: The heck? Just use a library.

Comment: Can you use something like `socketio-java` to send the data in bursts? Because, clients can't just spontaneously _be given_ data from the server, they have to _ask_ the server for data. Otherwise, why are you writing your own JSON output class in java? If you can't find one, try these guys: http://www.json.org/java/ There's no need to roll your own poor JSON emitter.

Comment: Don't write JSON by hand, use a library from http://json.org/java

Comment: No, clients can be spontaneously given data from the server. Check out sever sent events, that is what I am using. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/    Issues is not pushing it is accessing data using javascript, that too I have done for simle json, using :   var data = JSON.parse(e.data); .. Was getting error for array of data. Should be simple though. Will figure out myself in sometime.

Comment: Thanks Juan. That is very helpful. I was looking forward to some advice like that. I will try that.  But need to also into how using library to write JSON, changes the way we can read it using JS.

Comment: I think @saml should be working on an example for you...

Comment: @user969107 a) you've given no indication you're going to be using that library, or if you did, I completely missed it. You have to give us all the pieces to the puzzle. We can't read your mind. b) I gave the same link as four others have now given :p Some of us ARE faster than the rest. c) how is an SSE more useful than a websocket? You have to do all sorts of funky formatting right now, when a socket would give you much more control. This SSE sounds highly ... iffy to me. Granted, first time hearing of it.

Comment: @jcolebrand a) I gave no indication in the question that I am/will be using that library, but I asked for suggestions regarding better way to write JSON.  b) .. not sure what to write here c) SSE are one way communication channel from server to client so they are more useful in scenarios where you do not need bi directional flow and it also takes care of messages lost because of broken connection.  :)

Comment: Have you got a working java example for SSE, and does IE now support SSE? I only see working examples in php or python, and would only trust something like this to a eventing based server like nodejs.

Comment: @All I am new here, how to see who is editing the code in my question. And how to selectively apply those changes, as someone has edited is wrong.  :\

Comment: There's a link under your post that says "edit" click that.

Comment: Yea, that I know. But someone was suggesting changes to code in my question and those changes were actually getting reflected in the question without me having to accept/reject them. And When I clicked on "rollback to revision 2", it did not rolled back the changes. Anyways thank you

Comment: Because you wanted to rollback to the state it was in _before_ that edit, but you said to rollback to the state _after_ the edit. You really wanted to rollback to state 1

Comment: I've noticed a typo, you've not added `data:` to your closing brace at the very end of your actual question...

Comment: Yea, but it is there is original code. Sorry missed in copy pasting. Will correct that.

Comment: You missed what I meant, check again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please don't manually generate/parse JSON strings.  In Java, use [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) and in Javascript, use `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`.

MDN: [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

For outputting pairs of 5, you'd do something like:

```
String[] arr = strLine.split(",");
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
for(int i=0, j=0;i<arr.length;i+=2,j++){
   JSONObject dataObj = new JSONObject();
   dataObj.put("c1", arr[i]);
   dataObj.put("c2", arr[i+1]);
   array.put(j, dataObj);
   if ((j > 0) && (j % 5 ==0)) {
       out.append("data: " +array.toString() + "\n");
       out.flush();
       array = new JSONArray(); // start with a new one
   }
}
```

To access it on the client side, given your EventSource `source`:

```
source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data); // data is an array of {c1:...,c2:...} objects
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // it should be 5 in length
        console.log('c1 is: '+data[i].c1+' and c2 is '+data[i].c2);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the question. At best it's a comment. Downvoting because of this.

Comment: I tell him to use `JSON.parse` on the client side. How does that not answer the question?

Comment: I agree with jcolebrand. You should at least provide an example for Java, otherwise, should be a comment, I'll take my downvote back after you improve it

Comment: You're not even broaching the subject asked, you're simply finding the fastest way to gain rep. Yes, it's true that he should use JSON. How does he now get these 5 at a time onto the client? How does he generate correctly in Java using the library you've suggested? How does he properly return _only_ JSON from Java? How does he handle that little `data: [` he wants to put at the beginning?

Comment: I think jcolebrand got exactly what I am asking.  :) But thanks saml, for your advice too.  And thanks to jcolebrand for putting my question in right and better words. Though, I should have figured it out myself. I am not able to so far, doing something or other wrong.

Comment: After reading the link on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events SSE that he sent, I'm even more confounded, as there is no "proper" way to write JSON _and_ SSE. I would have to see some more complex examples to even process this. Does the server-side SSE library prepend those for you? Does the client auto-remove them? How do the JSON strings get recompiled? Lots of yucky questions here.

Comment: If I'm understanding your question more correctly, I've updated my answer to more accurately answer what you're asking.

Comment: @saml take a moment and read up on SSEs, do what I've done today, and become more acquainted with the request.

Comment: Why are you calling to `array.toString()` string when adding them to JSON objects? Also, you shouldn't be calling  `out.push(arr.toString())`. That will push a string but you want the JSONArray to be added so that the JSON for the array is not wrapped with quotes

Comment: @saml thanks ! You need not to read up on SSE. Whatever you answered is part of what I was looking for. :) Can you please give some JS code snippet too to access this JSON.

Comment: @jcole not sure what are you so confused about, can give you a working SSE example. Or may be I am missing something with SSE being a novice, but it seems to work for me.

Comment: We would LOVE a working SSE example in Java to a javascript JSON client, yes.

Comment: Actually just realized Juan is right. Saml's solution is not "right". :( .. Juan rightly pointed out two things.

Comment: @jcole, where shall I send/mail it to you. Or is there a way to upload it here on stackoverflow ?

Comment: Edit your original question way up above.

Comment: I dont' understand why I shouldn't call toString() when I write it to the output buffer.  That way it'll give you a JSON string in the event data and you can parse it with JSON.parse?

Comment: @saml because you'd like the output to be `{"a":[1,2,3]}`, not `{"a": "[1,2,3]"}` Your array is going to come out quoted, you don't want that. Mmm... I see now that what's being output is not valid JSON, so the `toString` call may not be too bad, but it's still not needed, since it will get called automatically when passed to `StringBuffer.append()`

Comment: Im confused.  JSONArray.toString doesn't quote things, does it?  That's how you convert a JSONArray to a String to put in the output buffer.

Comment: @saml I was kind of confused, I didn't realize you were passing it into a JSON buffer (as the OP needs), which kind of defeats the purpose of using JSON, see my edited comment above

Comment: I don't think it defeats the purpose of using JSON because OP can parse the data text with `JSON.parse` in the event handler, and the use of org.json guarantees well-formed JSON.

Comment: @saml, thanks. Yes it does. Can you please also give some Javascript code to access these at client side. I have edited some existing JS code in my question. If you can please modify that to work with new JSON ( 5 values)

Comment: `data: {...}` is not valid the JSON, and that's what the OP is asking for

Comment: Is the value of event.data "data: [...]"? I thought the client parses the event and sets it to: "[...]"

Comment: technically `data: [...]` would work, it would get received on the far end as `"[...]"` and so would then be parseable.

Answer (score 1):

To access a JSON string in JavaScript, just do this:

```
var myJson = JSON.parse(myJsonString);
```